# How to replace placeholders for environment variables in static `index.html` to actual values with brunch?

Tags: javascript, brunch

I use brunch for compilation of static assets. I've an `index.html` containing a `<script>` tag with environment variable placeholders. Based on the environment I want to change the placeholders to actual values. How can I do it the simplest way using brunch?

I tried several plugins, but although sounds to be a simple task, I fail to get anything replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [`handlebars-brunch`](https://github.com/brunch/handlebars-brunch) plugin from `master`, add

```
handlebars: {
  locals: {
    env: process.env
  }
}
```

to `plugins` in `brunch-config.js`, rename `index.html` to `index.html.hbs` and use it like this:

```
<script>
    alert("{{env.key}}")
</script>
```

Comment: It works, thank you! One note, on the current `master` it's enough to name the file `index.hbs`, it compiles it to `index.html`.

Comment: @fifigyuri yep, it is the feature you can rely on. I just use double extension for syntax highlighting.